# Conversión entre uint8_t y char es inseguro en c++

Tags: c++

Uno de las mayores preocupaciones que estoy sufriendo es el comportamiento indefinido según el estándar de c++.

En mi caso se trata de usar `fstream` para leer y escribir archivos pero las funciones `read` y `write` que usan `char*` tipo de argumento y yo estoy usando `uint8_t*` para procesar datos binarios porque estos se tratan como valores en rango 0-255 y no como caracteres.

Pues leyendo en diferentes foros de internet encontré información contradictoria sobre el comportamiento indefinido que produce usar `reinterpret_cast` específicamente con los tipos `char`, `signed char` y `unsigned char` porque resulta que el tipo `char` no es lo mismo que `signed char`, son dos tipos separados y es inseguro reinterpretar datos usando punteros. Para poner peor las cosas es posible que los tipos `unsigned char` no sean de 8 bits y por consecuencia `uint8_t` no es alias del mismo.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> datos = {65, 66, 67, 68};
    
    std::fstream file("archivo_binario.extesion", std::ios::out|std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    
    //aqui uso el reinterpret_cast para convertir el puntero interno del vector
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(datos.data()),datos.size());
    
    file.close();
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fstream` se define como `std::basic_fstream<char>`. Puedes consultarlo [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream).

Para leer un archivo con el tipo de dato que quieras, `uint8_t` en tu caso, puedes reemplazar la línea

```
std::fstream file("archivo_binario.extesion", std::ios::out|std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
```

Por

```
std::basic_fstream<uint8_t> file("archivo_binario.extesion", std::ios::out|std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
```

De modo que la funcionalidad será la misma y no necesitarás realizar ninguna conversión.

Comment: Por alguna extraña razón cuando uso la función read no lee los datos, simplemente no pasa nada, no muestra ningún error tampoco.

Comment: A mí me funciona perfecto. Lo probé tanto con `binary` como sin. Solo asegúrate de indicar el modo en que se abrirá el archivo si usas `fstream` y que si vas a leer un archivo, este exista.

Comment: simplemente no funciona. No pasa nada. Estoy usando windows 10,  mingw x64 version 10.2.0, codeblocks 20.03. Voy a arriesgarme con  reinterpret_cast porque no hay alternativa

Comment: No sé qué más decirte. A lo mejor esta otra respuesta ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172304/13419694